# FatalError when flushing after persisting datas

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, mariadb

I want to persist datas from a new Entity into the database, one of the most basic operation right?
But **when I flush**, I get the following fatal error:

```
FatalErrorException in DateTimeType.php line 53: 
Error: Call to a member function format() on string
```

So here's how I want to persist my datas, on Symfony 3.2, PHP 5.6 (sigh) and mariadb 10.3:

```php
$myEntity = new myEntity();
$myEntity->setFoo('a');
$myEntity->setBar('b');
$myEntity->setDateCreation(new \DateTime());

$this->em->persist($myEntity);
$this->em->flush();
```

My entity:

```php
class myEntity
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="sFoo", type="string",  length=255, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $foo;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="sBar", type="string",  length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $bar;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="dDateCreation", type="date")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    // Getter and setters are classics, here's the one for the date

    public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
    {
        $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;
    }

}
```

I get absolutely **no error** if I stop the script **before flushing**. When I dump my entity just before, **all the properties are set correctly** :

```
MyEntity {#2301 ▼
  -id: null
  -foo: "a"
  -bar "b
  -dateCreation: DateTime {#2204 ▼
    +"date": "2020-07-06 12:32:17.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
  }
}
```

From the database side : the columns seems to be correctly set: sFoo and sBar are `VARCHAR(255)` dDateCreation is `date`.

I eventually changed the date fields type from date to string, with a string as argument like "20200706", just for trying. And... I get the same error, even if there are no DateTime anymore involved in this.

Either I'm completely blind and there is an obvious thing I forgot in the code I've posted, or the reason comes from elsewhere.

I tried the same operation with an other Entity, same result.

Comment: Is `dateCreation` the only property of type DateTime? Is this the only Entity involved in this `flush`?

Comment: I've not used MariaDB in some time. Perhaps it's a configuration issue. Check [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-and-time-data-types/). Maybe you cannot insert a DateTime into a Date column. Try changing it in your entity to type datetime.

Comment: Hello, @simon.ro yes, there is an other Date property. At Martin M well, normally I can, I've tried on a an other project. A Date property will get only the Date part from a DateTime. Anyway : I haven't found how, but I've figured it only comes from a controller... That's strange, since I didn't find any Event Subscriber or anything with any method of this Controller. So I found how to avoid it, but I havn't found the reason of this. My flush works fine in any other controller. Thanks everyone for your help.